# How to do Binary search in part of a list efficiently?

Tags: java, binary-search

In JAVA : I am trying to do an exponential search and then a binary search on part of list however i cannot configure the low and high to be set on the list, i end up making a new array to store that part of the list and then do binary search and adjust index to correspond to the original list; It works but is hardly efficient.

Can anyone help figure out the right way to do this without making another array ?

```
int[] binary_search = new int[(range_upper - range_lower + 1)];

            int k_for_list = range_lower;
            for(int k =0; k < binary_search.length; k++)
                {
                    binary_search[k] = l2.getId(k_for_list);
                    k_for_list++;
                }


            int low = 0;
            int high = binary_search.length - 1;

             while(high >= low) 
             {
                 int middle = (low + high) / 2;
                 if(binary_search[middle] == l1.getId(i1)) 
                    {
                     result.addPosting(l1.getId(i1), l1.getScore(i1) + l2.getScore(middle + range_lower));
                     element_not_found = 1;
                     i2 = middle + range_lower;                            
                    }

                 if(binary_search[middle] < l1.getId(i1))
                            low = middle + 1;
                  else
                            high = middle - 1;
              }
```

Comment: What are the specific problems you're encountering with "configuring the low and high to be set on the list"?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Basically i am trying to implement a galloping search; I am finding a subarray from a array by exponential search and then doing binary search in this subarray; and for the binary search if i use the original index of the list i end up searching in a different range, so i copy the index and make a new array copied from this subarray and search there with the usual high and low i.e 0 and the array.length-1 and map it back; I want to avoid making this array and assignment but i cannot figure out if there is a way to do this search in the subarray with some smart index values.

Comment: Why do you think it needs to be "smart". Just use range_lower and range_upper instead of 0 and length - 1 as your bounds.

Comment: @JBNizet I tried earlier using these metrics, didnt help. But after your comment i debugged again for other errors and it worked finally with the original range_lower and range _upper values. Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use method

```
List<Integer> list = l2.subList(range_lower, range_upper);
```

to create a view of your list and than perform:

```
Collections.binarySearch(list, key);
```

Comment: Thank you for this alternative, however this will cost me more execution, so i have just used the actually range_lower and range_upper values for binary search instead of making a list.